# Check if is user currently scrolling

Tags: wpf, scroll, controls

How can I check if is user currently scrolling for example richTextBox or another control.

Comment: How do you mean "Scrolling"? There is the ScrollChanged event for a `ScrollViewer` and ValueChanged for `ScrollBar`. What is it that you're trying to solve?

Comment: This I need, thank I use ScrollChanged event  and create property IsScrolling if e.VerticalChange != 0 I set IsScrolling on true.

Comment: @Meleak you can post your comment as answer :)

Comment: Alright, posted an answer from the comment:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the ScrollChanged event for a `ScrollViewer` and ValueChanged event for a `ScrollBar`

```
<ScrollViewer ...
              ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged"

<ScrollBar ...
           ValueChanged="ScrollBar_ValueChanged"
```